# Why would replaced Common function cause memory issues?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4.2.1 (so appreciate at time of writing its not the latest), but am wondering why the following code, based on the principle here (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/extending/common.html) would not work? (I appreciate this doesn't return / is incomplete!)

```
function config(string $name, bool $getShared = true){
    $cache = Services::cache();
}
```

Its not just the cache option - using a `$db = \Config\Database::connect();` also fails with `Allowed memory size ...` which of course I have tweaked on the server but with no effect. Ideally I'd like to use my custom Common functions otherwise will have to use a separate Library.

Comment: The line `$cache = Services::cache();` causes my project to not even send a response `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: For auto-testing yes it will. Just add `echo $name;`.

Comment: Please provide more context to your question.  I.e 1. From where are you initializing the `cache` service?  2. What are you really up to?

Comment: My purpose is to use a database (I am aware of the CI4 settings library) to store and retrieve my configuration settings. I'm using a Common.php which is in a custom location but basically any calls to external elements here aren't working. They're tripping on memory. I've got other functions in the common file such as Lang which works perfectly fine so I'm 99% sure its not a system configuration issue.